# Terminology for Digitally Interpretting Environment

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am looking into coding a crude hobby C++ program that can Analyse a video stream and identify objects in that environment/frame (object depth & contours/shape). As this is not a trivial thing to do can you suggest any tutorials for this?

What is the term for this? Is there a term or area of expertise for this? 'Computer Vision' seems too broad of a term I believe. Maybe Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)? Object Detection? Environment Analysis?

If I know the term I can then search for tutorials. Also, if I know the algorithms involved I can search for these to get an idea how they work. Any advice of algorithms and approaches? Hough Circles, Colour identification, just simple contour identification (but how would I differentiate between objects), etc? I don't think Haar Cascade files would be appropriate/efficient solution because the program will encounter many different objects - its more about identifying obstacles and attempting a crude identification of an objects shape and depth.

Comment: Semantic segmentation